# Отсутствуют параметры суперглобального массива FILES

Tags: php, ооп, передача-данных

Столкнулся с проблемой, при добавлении поста с изображением ,передается файл и проходит проверку на существование и так далее.Дело в том,что в  суперглобальном  массиве FILES из всех параметров которые должен он содержать при передаче файла,имеется только имя $_FILES['file']['name'], а остальных нет,такие как $_FILES['file']['type'] и так далее.Не знаю в чем проблема

Метод проверки который находится в одном из классов

```
    private function imgAdd(){

        if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){

            //даем уникальное имя файлу по времени добавления в секундах
            $img = time() . "_" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            //временное имя
            $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            //тип файла
            $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
            //место хранения изображения
            $destination = "../img/" . $img;


            if (strpos($fileType, 'image') === false) {

            }else{
                $result = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $destination);

                if ($result){
                    $this->img = $img;

                    $res = true;

                }
                else{
                    $res = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $res = false;
        }

        return $res;

    }
```